# Excel VBA code to change add 1 year to a column if the check box in the row is checked

Tags: vba, excel

I need help writing a code that will add 1 year to the date in Column C(starting at C2) only if a check box(Form Control) in the same column is checked, then clear all check boxes, all this accomplished by clicking a button(Form Control).

This is my current code for the button, which just adds 1 year to C2:

```
Sub Button211_Click()
Range("$C2").Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CDate(Range("$C2")))
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be a proper check box? It might be easier if you did this with an "x" or something like that in a cell. It's possible otherwise, but not as easy. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It does not need to be a check box, if it is easier with "x" thats fine. While trying different things I did associate each check box to the neighboring cell, so if its checked the cell value is "True" if not checked="False". This would fall in line with your "x" value in a cell, no?

Comment: If you need any more help or have any questions, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

[image: Demo]

The code to add a year to a range is pretty trivial

You can use this sub and just pass it a range

```
Sub AddYearToRange(TheRange As Range)
Dim c
For Each c In TheRange
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then c.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, c.Value)
Next c
End Sub
```

Example usage:

`AddYearToRange [C2:C5]`

`AddYearToRange Range("C2:C5")`

`AddYearToRange Selection`

`AddYearToRange Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C5")`

If you want to do something like put an X next to the cell when it is changed, you can add this:

```
Sub AddYearToRange(TheRange As Range)
Dim c
For Each c In TheRange
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then
        c.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, c.Value)
        c.offset(0,1).Value = "X"
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

If you only want to do it if a checkbox is checked, you can add this:

```
Sub AddYearToRange(TheRange As Range, CheckboxValue As Integer)
'Unchecked = xlOff = -4146
'Checked = 1
'Multi-check checkbox = 2
If CheckboxValue <> 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim c
For Each c In TheRange
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then
        c.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, c.Value)
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = "X" 'This line places an X one column to the right
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Then, just pass the checkbox value to it

Example Usage:

`AddYearToRange [C2:C5], CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value`

^ This example will only add a year to the range if the check box is checked.